# to use escape character rightly

Tags: r, escaping

i found it is difficult to create  character :  " is entered as \ "
when i input in R:

> " is entered as \"

`+`

> " is entered as \ "

[1] " is entered as  "

```
>" is entered as \\ "
```

[1] " is entered as \ "

```
>" is entered as \\"
```

[1] " is entered as \"

how can i get character " is entered as \ "?

---

i  am still confused

> cat("is entered as \" )

is entered as >

```
> "is entered as \\"
```

[1] "is entered as \"

```
> print ("is entered as \\")
```

[1] "is entered as \"

Comment: @ttmaccer, is that a pun? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"hoge \\"` is actually `hoge \`

`print` shows `\` as `\\`, so you find `\\` for `\`.

try `cat`:

```
> cat("is entered as \\" )
is entered as \
```

and probably `nchar` will manifest this:

```
> nchar("\\" )
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were trying to achieve?:

```
> x <- "START \" is entered as \\\" END"
> cat(x)
```

Gives:

> START " is entered as \" END

You have to escape both the double quote `"`, and the backslash `\`, in order to have them display normally.

To clear up any confusion between whether the double quotes printed in the output are part of the string, or just symbols that wrap around the string, I've added `START` at the start of the string and `END` at the end.